# 'all' hook and get_option issue

Tags: plugins, options

code listing: http://pastebin.com/0LEqgRUZ

I ran into a trouble with my plugin. (It is a class based plugin actually)
I'm trying to use `get_option` function. When I just make `var_dump(get_option('option_name', 1))` somewhere in `plugin_options` function (you'll see the code listing) - it outputs `int(1)`

The problem is that I cannot use `get_option` inside my `log_to` method.
The `log_to` method is bound to 'all' hook. So I guess that's why it doesn't work. (even `wp` is not loading at all)

Anyone knows the resolution?

Comment: Please post the relevant code inline here. A question should not rely on a third party site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_option` fires hooks itself](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/option.php#L32) so you are triggering a infinite loop (or something similar if not actually infinite). Your callback calls `get_option`, which triggers the hooks used by `get_option`. Each hook triggers the callback again, which used `get_option` which triggers the hooks used by `get_option`. And so on...

Get your option value in the constructor, outside of the callback method. That way, when your callback runs it is inadvertently triggering itself. Proof of concept:

```
class WP_Test_Logging_Plugin {

  static $data = array();

  public function __construct() {
    $this->data = get_option('option_name', 1);
    add_action( 'all', array( $this, 'log_to' ) );
  }

  public function log_to() {
    $hook = current_filter();
    var_dump($hook,$this->data);
  }
}
$ntlp = new WP_Test_Logging_Plugin();
```

Comment: Yep, this is helpful. But also, I can't get why I am unable to add an option to a database. I tried both register_setting and add_action. No result.

Comment: Your problem with `register_setting` and with `add_action` is not part of the original question but if you are attempting to use those inside the callback you are going to have the same issue described in this answer.

Comment: oh, yeah. You're quite right. Have just changed it the appropriate way. Thank you a lot!

Comment: If this solved the question please [mark it as "Accepted"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). Look for the check mark on the left.

Comment: Excuse me by the way. I really need to process form submission somehow. But I seen to run into the same trouble with endless loop. Are there any ways to go about it in my case? Thanks