# 'all' hook and add_action issue (class based plugin)

Tags: plugins, loop

I am currently having a problem with my custom made plugin. It actually logs all the actions/filters fired to a file (or to screen). I need to update my options in the db somehow when submitting the form. Here's the code listing itself:

```
class WP_Test_Logging_Plugin {

//required for the file name
private $yymmddhhmmss;
private $data;

public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'all', array( $this, 'log_to' ) );
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'menu' ) );
    add_action( 'admin_print_styles', array( $this, 'plugin_theme_style' ) );
    add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'on_admin_form_submit' ) );
    $this->yymmddhhmmss = date( 'YMDHis' );
    if ( get_option( 'where_to_log_to' ) == false ) {
        update_option( 'where_to_log_to', 1 );
    }
    $this->data = get_option( 'where_to_log_to' );
}
```

the method I use to process the form

```
public function on_admin_form_submit() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['selection'] ) ) {
        update_option( 'where_to_log_to', $_POST['selection'] );
    }
}
```

Is there a way to go about it?
Thanks!

Comment: @s_ha_dum, could you help me with this?

Comment: @toscho , excuse me. I am just new to stackexchange. Trying to learn using it in an appropriate way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `template_redirect` is a front end hook. It never fires on your backend save. You need to choose a backend hook such as `admin_init` to hook your function.

Secondly, [based on your pastebin from you other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/116117/21376), your code has the `checked` attribute hard-coded for both of your radio boxes, thus causing it to default to the last one all the time. You are going to want to edit your form like so:

```
<input type="radio" <?php checked($this->data, 1); ?> value="1" name="selection" >
```

Third, you need to make sure that both of your radio buttons have a `value` attribute.

Fourth, you need to update the option when you save so...

```
public function on_admin_form_submit() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['selection'] ) ) {
      if ($_POST['selection'] == 1){
        update_option( 'where_to_log_to', 1 );
      } else {
        update_option( 'where_to_log_to', 2 );
      }
    }
    $this->data = get_option( 'where_to_log_to', 1 );
}
```

Notice that I explicitly saved the values 1 and 2.

I think that's got it.

Comment: ok. i will test it in a moment. could you tell me if it is allowed to share contact details in the comments? i just could send you my zip package.

Comment: tested. it is still not changing my option.

Comment: [In a comment to my answer on your other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116121/21376) you stated "But I seen to run into the same trouble with endless loop." Is that not correct? Do you have an infinite loop or not?

Comment: Actually, nope. I'm testing the plugin and there's no infinite loop. I still wonder why it doesn't change my option in the database. It definitely changes the option if i state in in the __constructor(). But nowhere else.

Comment: @AlexHerrmann : see the edit